# Worried I committed shirk?

Tags: shirk, jinn

I was fascinated by jinns and wanted to them to do me small favors and speak with them and have them follow me around n I asked my friend how it was possible but he didnt know. I have never actually done anything to summon them. Have I committed shirk? I didn’t even know it was haram or shirk at that time I just Wanted to do it and thought it was cool at the time. So have I committed shirk for just wanting to do it without actually doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it breaking the law when I am planning on driving over 100mph but I never did it?

Shirk is a verb. A verb is an action. Has the action been done?

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you committed shirk run to Allah you are worried this means you fear Allah this is good run to him and seek his forgiveness and promise Allah not to do it again he says in the Quran “he is most merciful.” Promise him not do it again and Allah will forgive you.